# Ruby on Rails changing rows and column number displayed on page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby on Rails
I created a database and have it so someone can upload a story to the database.  It has a title and content.  It is displayed on the page as a 40 column 20 row textfield.  I can't figure out how to change it to make the text field bigger.

This is what is in the file

`<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>`

this is what the page source says was created on the page

`<div class="field">
    <label for="story_content">Content</label><br />
    <textarea cols="40" id="story_content" name="story[content]" rows="20">`

I want to change it so I can make the field bigger, to look more natural instead of so skinny and long.  So the question is where is it stored how big the textfield is going to be so I can change it

Answer (score 1):

For this you may use like this:

```
<%= f.text_area :message, :id => "message_area", :cols => 10, :rows => 10 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better set cols and rows in your .css file with width and height of the imput fields
For example:

```
imput#post_content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

It also be useful for responsible design. 
Think it should help.